# Internal server error after editing .htaccess in CakePHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, browser-cache

I want to disable the browser cache for CSS, images and scripts by adding this code to `webroot/.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "(.)*.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1"
</FilesMatch>
```

This is the error:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

When I add a command to every `.htaccess` file in [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP), I receive this error!

Comment: where is error log for details?

Comment: Is the module properly installed?

Comment: I think mod_headers, but not really sure. Try what i posted in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$">
```

Improved (note I removed "jpg"):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$">
```

Comment: same internal server error. should i active any apache module?

Comment: Try to enable mod_headers and mod_expires

Comment: Definitively, check if mod_headers is enabled: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html